# no resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_Below' in package 'android'....?

Tags: android

I got the following **error**:

> no resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_Below' in package
>   'android'

```
<fragment                     <--Got the error in this line-->
    android:id = "@+id/map"
    android:name = "com.google.android.gms.maps.Mapfragment"
    android:layout_Below = "@+id/header"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent" />
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_below

Answer (score 1):

Use a lowercase 'b': `android:layout_below`

It's worth noting that Eclipse (and probably other IDEs) allow auto-completion of things like this so you don't make typing mistakes. In Eclipse you can use Ctrl+Space (windows) or Control+Space (mac)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the lowercase :

```
android:layout_below="@+id/header"
```

also in IDEs like Eclipse and Intellij, which the latter is more stable, you can take advantage of IntelliSense and AutoCompletion features.